# How to implement that

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to add a button and associate menu to it , I mean like the screen shot in the following link be appear containing uipicker

I want to implement as attached uipicker as in the following screenshot: [image: ipad layout]

Original Image: http://www.zshare.net/image/8968507074a9e0c0/

any suggession please

Comment: First suggestion - don't use a service to share images that makes users wait 45 seconds to see it. Use img.ur or imageshack.us instead.

Comment: Can't you use a UIPicker for that?

Comment: How to use it , could u give me example in how to implement that

Comment: -1 for extremely bad question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily implement it using a uiscrollview. just create all the stuff in uiscrollview and appear it here..